# Changing format from time to data time format in SAS

Tags: sas

Currently , I have date column in time format ,I want to change it to date time stamp format I.e ( I want the date column to look like 12nov 2020 12:03:45:00 )
Could someone help me on this ?

Comment: Please show more details about the variable. What is the TYPE of the variable (numeric or character).  Does it currently have a FORMAT attached to it? If so what format.  Show some example values.  Show the values with the current format and also without a format (or use BEST for numeric and $ for character).  Show what value (or what string you want displayed when the value is formatted) for the example values.

Answer (score 0):

According to [@KurtBremser:](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/date-to-datetime-conversion/td-p/451534)

> SAS dates are counts of days, SAS datetimes are counts of seconds.

```
datetime = dhms(date,0,0,0);
```

> will convert a date to a datetime. Or multiply by 86400.

Comment: I have the time format column value as 995124 upon applying format datetime18. On the time column the value is changed to 09JUL73:12:52:31 could you tell me where Iam going wrong cause year is looking weird

Answer (score 0):

A column showing a time representation `hh:mm:ss` can be one of three things:

1. A character column type containing digit characters `0`-`9` and `:`
2. A number column type containing a **SAS time value** being displayed as `hh:mm:ss` with the time format `TIME8.`
3. A number column type containing a **SAS datetime value** being displayed as `hh:mm:ss` with the datetime format `TOD.`

This sample program demonstrates how different kinds of values can all *look* the same when viewed.

```
data have;
  v1 = '12:34:56';
  v2 = hms(12,34,56);
  v3 = dhms(today(),12,34,56);

  put v1= / v2= time8. / v3=tod. / v3=datetime18.;
run;
------ LOG ------
v1=12:34:56
v2=12:34:56
v3=12:34:56
v3=25NOV20:12:34:56
```

Only #3 has enough information in the raw value to be formatted as `ddmmmyyy:hh:mm:ss`

```
format myDate datetime18.;
```

#2 requires computing a new value assuming something about the date part

```
* supposing myDate contains only time values (00:00:00 to 23:59:59) for today;

myNewDate = dhms(today(),0,0,0) + myDate;
format myNewDate datetime18.;
```

#1 requires interpretation through `INPUT` and a date assumption

```
* supposing myDate contains "hh:mm:ss" for today

myNewDate = dhms(today(),0,0,0) + input(myDate,time8.);
format myNewDate datetime18.;
```

Comment: My time column has values like 995124 ,1005424 could you please tell me how to change these time values to date time format

Comment: Those numbers don't correspond to contemporary datetime numbers.  The numbers (as seconds) correspond to ~276 and ~279 hours respectively.  Where did the values come from and do you have other values to contrast with ?